# How can I update custom `react-draft-wysiwyg` icons for `blockType` options?

Tags: reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I have the following `Editor` utilizing `react-draft-wysiwyg`:

```
<Editor
    // ...other props
    toolbar={toolbarOptions}
/>
```

The `toolbarOptions` are set up to handle custom icons for all of my options. I followed a similar pattern for `blockType` options ('H1' and 'H2' here) as the other options, as the icons are successfully being applied. The `H1` and `H2` buttons appear in the toolbar, but without the custom icons:

```
const toolbarOptions = {
    options: ['blockType', 'inline', 'list', 'link', 'history'],
    blockType: {
        inDropdown: false,
        options: ['H1', 'H2'],
        H1: {                       // not working
            icon: HeaderOneIcon,
            className: ""
        },
        H2: {                       // not working
            icon: HeaderTwoIcon,
            className: ""
        }
    },
    inline: {  
        options: [ 'bold', 'italic' ],  
        bold: { 
            icon: BoldIcon,
            className: "text-editor-icon-left text-editor-bold-button" 
        },
        italic: {
            icon: ItalicIcon, 
            className: "text-editor-icon-left" 
        },
    },
    list: { 
        options: ['unordered', 'ordered'],
        unordered: { icon: FormatListBulletedIcon, className: "text-editor-icon-left" },
        ordered: { icon: FormatListNumberedIcon, className: "text-editor-icon-left" },
    },
    link: { 
        options: ['link'],
        link: { icon: LinkIcon, className: "text-editor-icon-left" }, 
    },
    history: {
        undo: { icon: UndoIcon, className: "text-editor-icon-right" },
        redo: { icon: RedoIcon, className: "text-editor-icon-right" },
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the key values from `H1`/`H2` to `h1`/`h2`, `"H1"`/`"H2"`, and `"h1"`/`"h2"`, and I've also tried adding and removing `classNames` from those options. Anyone know what I am missing here?